# Bigram and trigram probability python

Tags: python, nltk

I really need help to understand the process of probability estimating. 
So I calculated the count of bigrams in a corpus:

```
import nltk
bigram_p = {}

for sentence in corpus:
    tokens = sentence.split()
    tokens = [START_SYMBOL] + tokens #Add a start symbol 
    #so the first word would count as bigram
    bigrams = (tuple(nltk.bigrams(tokens)))
    for bigram in bigrams:
        if bigram not in bigram_p:
           bigram_p[bigram] = 1
        else:
           bigram_p[bigram] += 1

        for bigram in bigram_p:
            if bigram[0] == '*':  
                bigram_p[bigram] = math.log(bigram_p[bigram]/unigram_p[('STOP',)],2)
            else:
                bigram_p[bigram] = math.log(bigram_p[bigram]/unigram_p[(word[0],)],2)
```

but I get a KeyError - math domain error - and I can't understand why. Pleas explain to me my error and what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are getting that error in some of the `math.log` lines. That error only means that you are passing an argument which doesn't have a `log` operation defined, e.g.

```
import math

# Input is zero
math.log(0)  # ValueError: math domain error

# Input is negative
math.log(-1)  # ValueError: math domain error
```

One of your expresions `bigram_p[bigram]/unigram_p[('STOP',)]` or `math.log(bigram_p[bigram]/unigram_p[(word[0],)]` is producing a zero or negative input.

Note that division operator (`/`) in python 2.7 is an integer division, so results are truncated to integer if both arguments are integer:

```
1 / 2    # => 0, because 1 and 2 are integers
1. / 2   # => 0.5, because 1. is a float
1.0 / 2  # => 0.5, because 1.0 is a float
```

If you want a more *intuitive* behavior of the division operaror, add to your file,

```
from __future__ import division
```

Here are the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) for that import if you want to understand more about it.

EDIT:

If you can't/don't want to use the import trick, you can convert to float a number either by multiplying by a float `n * 1.0` or with a built-in function `float(n)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped!

Comment: @Repzz If this answer helped you to solve your problem, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).